# Navigate website with selenium. Click() not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping, webdriverwait

**Edit: Changed to Lakers game as the other one started**

I'm learning how to webscrape betting odds and I've been stuck on this problem all day. When I load this website Betway, it goes to the 'Main Markets'(see image below). I would like to go to other tabs, e.g. 'Game Props' or '1st Half'.

```
url = "https://sports.betway.com/en/sports/evt/6183976"
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div")
element.click()
```

On other websites I've been able to use the [find by elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB03D.png) function, followed by the click() function to navigate through pages. I can't get them to work on this site. The bottom image I included is the code from the website when I inspect it. I would really appreciate some advice here!

[image: Website]

[image]

Comment: please procide your `click` code so we know how you are accessing the element

Comment: @MZ I've updated what I'm doing. I got the Xpath from the selected line of the bottom screenshot.

Comment: doesn't seem like I can find that specific element – the xpath isn't working in browser

Comment: The game has started so I think the links have changed. I'll try to put in a new game with new links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the tab with text as **Game Props** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(., 'login or register')]"))).click()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

- Browser Snapshot:

[image: betway]